# Checkboxes in listbox not getting checked via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, binding, listbox

I'm trying to check all the checkboxes through a binding..
The getChecked property does get changed to true after clicking the button but the checkboxes are just not getting checked. Does someone see what I'm doing wrong here? This is the XAML code for the listbox.

```
<ListBox Name="scroll"  ItemContainerStyle ="{StaticResource _ListBoxItemStyle}" Tag="{Binding SortingIndex}"  BorderBrush="#C62828" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="checkboxStack">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=getChecked}"  Content="{Binding Path=vraag}"  Style="{StaticResource LifesaversCheckBoxesA}"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=Tag}" Content="{Binding Path=antwoorden[0]}" FontSize="15" />
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=Tag}" Content="{Binding Path=antwoorden[1]}" FontSize="15" />
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=Tag}" Content="{Binding Path=antwoorden[2]}" FontSize="15" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This is the event handler for the button I made to change the getChecked boolean to true for each vraag in vragenLijst. The sample data is just to generate some random strings.

```
public partial class LivesaversWindow : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Vraag> vragenLijst;
    public LivesaversWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vragenLijst = new VragenList(SampleData.vragen());

        scroll.ItemsSource = vragenLijst;

    }

    private void alles_Selecteren(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)select.Content == "Alles selecteren")
        {
            foreach(Vraag vraag in vragenLijst)
            {
                vraag.getChecked = true;

            }
            select.Content = "Alles deselecteren";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Vraag vraag in vragenLijst)
            {
                    vraag.getChecked = false;
            }
            select.Content = "Alles selecteren";
        }
    }
```

And these are the 2 classes I'm using.

```
    public class Vraag 
{
    public List<string> antwoorden { get; set; }
    public string vraag { get; set; }
    public Boolean getChecked { get; set; }
}





 public class VragenList : ObservableCollection<Vraag>
{
    public VragenList(List<Vraag> vragen) :base()
    {
        foreach (var vraag in vragen)
        {
            Add(vraag);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Vraag is not implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface. Therefore the UI is not registering any changes that are made to your objects displaying in the view:

So bascially what you need to do is implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged-Interface kind of like this:

```
public class Vraag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> antwoorden { get; set; }
    public string vraag { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked;

    public bool getChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem. Just as a sidenode: It is allways kind of nice to create a base class implemeting the INotifyPropertyChanged interface with the PropertyChangedEventHandler and the OnPropertyChanged-Method, so you can just use it in any classes you want to show in your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Your class Vraag must implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface